# Git Bash asks for SSH passphrase on first run after every PC reboot

Tags: git-bash, ssh-agent

Every time I start up Git Bash after restarting my Windows 10 PC it asks me for the passphrase for my SSH key.

I didn't used to have this problem, and I've never seen it anywhere else; I use Git Bash at work and have never seen this problem there.

```
Initializing new SSH agent...
succeeded
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

If I close the Git Bash window and open a new one, the new window doesn't prompt me for a passphrase. Nor will any subsequent window. It doesn't seem to matter whether I enter a passphrase in the first window or not.

However, if I restart, the first Git Bash window will again prompt me for a passphrase.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Git. I've also tried running `ssh-add -k path/to/key`. Neither approach worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I close the Git Bash window and open a new one, the new window doesn't prompt me for a passphrase.

That is because your `~/.bashrc` (under `%USERPROFILE%`) [must have launched the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows), which will cache your passphrase for the time of your Windows session.
But when restarting Windows, you will need to enter the passphrase again.

Comment: Thank you! I removed those lines from my `.bashrc` and finally the prompt went away.

Comment: I have the same problem but I can not find the ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: @JoyKarmoker What OS do you have?

Comment: @VonC Windows 11

Comment: @JoyKarmoker then there is no .bashrc in %USERPROFILE% by default. Does the issue persists with Git For Windows 2.34.1?

Comment: @VonC I have the git version `2.31.1.windows.1`. Do I have to update it?

Comment: @JoyKarmoker for testing, yes. Check also your environment variables, for anything related to SSH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239627/discussion-between-joy-karmoker-and-vonc).